# psychopy.logging: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'

Tags: logging, psychopy

I'm running a github code with python 2.7. I've recieved this error:

- File "...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psychopy\logging.py", line 282, in log
  if level < self.lowestTarget:

  TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'*

While "logging" is a predefined python module.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: My guess would be that level is a function and you want level(). But read the error message: It tells you exactly that. You can’t compare a function and an Int.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thank you. But "logging" is a predefined module and I receive this error without changing the main code.

Comment: I think there would have more lines to this error message? Could you update your question to show all the lines of the error so we can see what was making the call to logging etc?